# PHP Phar created with Phar::createDefaultStub running as CLI in browser

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, phar

I have an application I want to package as a PHAR with both CLI and web interfaces (it acts as an API to wider system so I'd like to avoid reproducing the same libraries across two PHAR archives). The 'bug' im encountering is that the PHAR always acts like it's run from the command line when created with createDefaultStub.

```
<?php
try {
$phar = new Phar('myphar.phar');
$phar['cli.php'] = '<?php echo "CLI"; ?>';
$phar['web.php'] = '<?php echo "Web"; ?>';
$phar->setDefaultStub('cli.php', 'web.php');
// this is the same as:
// $phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('cli.php', 'web/index.php'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
// handle errors
}
?>
```

If I run the phar created from the above code which was taken directly from (http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.createdefaultstub.php from the command line with

```
php.exe myphar.phar
```

I see, "CLI" as expected, but I also see this from the web also.

There is a documented bug from 2010, but since it appears unsolved and not many cases available I'm wondering if its something I'm doing wrong at my end.

PHP Bug Report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52322&edit=2

Things I've done to try and diagnose:

Tested on PHP *5.4.11, 5.3.21, 5.2.17*
The phar was recreated under each version also.

Tried on a clean install of the latest XAMPP.

PHP.ini settings

```
detect_unicode = Off
phar.readonly = Off
phar.require_hash = Off
```

Debugged with echo from cli.php of:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Both return as expected, these are the values used in the default stub to check if it's running on the web.

I really am at a loss here and wondered if anybody had ideas about where to turn next?

Writing a custom stub is an option, but likely something is going wrong behind the scenes that will trip me up later on.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I believe you're not supposed to be doing this. For example, for CLI, I'd include a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env php`), but this would also be sent to the browser - not good.

Comment: We are in 2016 and i am also getting the same issue, did you find any solution ?